# Svg image inside img tag with a gif doesnt play

Tags: html, image, svg

I wanted to ask if i take an svg image which has a gif inside can be used on web as an image tag. For example

```
<img src="example.svg" />
```

So my `example.svg` has a gif inside it, but when i place the image tag in an html the gif doesn't play whereas if i open that image  in a new tab it plays. Is there any way it can be played?

Comment: Do you mean that the gif is visible but doesn't animate or that the gif is not visible at all?

Comment: @RobertLongson The gif is visible but doesnt animate, i also tried Data uri method but still doesnt work.

Comment: If you're using Firefox it could be [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1242256) which I've fixed for Firefox 48.

Answer (score 1):

SVGs that are embedded with `<img>` must be self contained.  This a browser rule.  If your SVG references a GIF in a third file, then it will not work.

You can either embed the GIF into your SVG as a Data URI.  Or you could switch to using `<object>` instead.

Comment: "SVGs that are embedded with <img> must be self contained." Reference?

Answer (score 1):

[**Convert and Image to data Uri using browser**](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/convert-an-image-to-a-data-uri-with-your-browser/)

This trick works in Chrome and newer versions of Opera, since they use the same rendering engine.

1. Load the page that contains your image (loading the image directly won't work) and right-click on it. Select Inspect Element.

Chrome data URIs - Step 1

2. You'll see the console appear. Now click on the value of the src attribute.

Chrome data URIs - Step 2

3. The console will switch to the Resources tab and highlight the image. Right click on it and select Copy Image As Data URL.

Chrome data URIs - Step 3

4. Now just paste it into your HTML or CSS!

This is one method another is given belo

[Using javascript and Canvas](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript)

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        // Get raw image data
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

        // ... or get as Data URI
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    };

    image.src = url;
}
```